# Find the vertical & horizontal factors and horizontal translation of an exponential function when only given certain points (high school math).

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I really need help solving this problem, and I hope I came to the right place (this is my first time on this site)! For a certain exponential function, I was given the points **(-10, 1.9968)**, **(-9,1.984)**, **(-8, 1.92)**, **(-7,1.6)** and **(-6,0)**. By the points, I was able to make some conclusions for the exponential function:

> *y = -a(5)^[k(x-d)] +2*,

the *b-value is 5*, the *c-value (or the asymptote) is 2*, and the *a-value is negative*, as the function portrays to be decaying. I am in need of finding the a, k and d values of this exponential function, as I need it for a math assignment due soon. I would like to know if this is high school level math, as I may be interpreting the question differently. Thank you very much and I appreciate all your replies.

Comment: least squares between log y and x

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra parameter in your equation because $5^{-kd}$ can be absorbed into $a$, so now your equation is $y=-a5^{kx}+2$.  If you subtract $2$ and take the log you get $\log_5(2-y)=\log_5(a)+kx$.  This is a straight line in $x$ vs $\log_5(2-y)$ and you should be able to find $k$.  I plotted the points and they look to fit a straight line nicely.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your efforts in helping me! I was able to algebraically discover that the k value is 1. How exactly would I find the remaining two variables; a and d variables.

Comment: Then $a$ and $d$ are equivalent just as I said.  You can just set $d$ to zero and find the proper $a$.  $d$ just makes a factor of $5^{-kd}$, and given $k=1$ this is $5^{-d}$.  It is a multiplicative factor just like $a$, so the two of them  are only one variable.  If there is no noise in your data, you can just take one point and evaluate $a$.  Otherwise you can compute $a$ from each point and take some sort of average.